# `selectNextSuggestion` shortcuts for `show all commands` not work

Tags: visual-studio-code

I set shortcut `ctrl n` and `ctrl p` for `selectNextSuggestion` and `selectPrevioiusSuggestion`. And I disable the shortcut `ctrl n` for `workbench.action.files.newUntitledFile`

After pressing `ctrl shift p`, `all commands` pops out with many suggestions.
[image]

After pressing `ctrl n` , nothing happens. This is log meassage:

```bash
[2022-06-01 12:47:09.682] [renderer1] [info] [KeybindingService]: / Received  keydown event - modifiers: [ctrl], code: ControlLeft, keyCode: 17, key: Control
[2022-06-01 12:47:09.682] [renderer1] [info] [KeybindingService]: | Converted keydown event - modifiers: [ctrl], code: ControlLeft, keyCode: 5 ('Ctrl')
[2022-06-01 12:47:09.682] [renderer1] [info] [KeybindingService]: \ Keyboard event cannot be dispatched in keydown phase.
[2022-06-01 12:47:09.701] [renderer1] [info] [KeybindingService]: / Received  keydown event - modifiers: [ctrl], code: KeyN, keyCode: 78, key: n
[2022-06-01 12:47:09.701] [renderer1] [info] [KeybindingService]: | Converted keydown event - modifiers: [ctrl], code: KeyN, keyCode: 44 ('N')
[2022-06-01 12:47:09.702] [renderer1] [info] [KeybindingService]: | Resolving ctrl+[KeyN]
[2022-06-01 12:47:09.702] [renderer1] [info] [KeybindingService]: \ From 1 keybinding entries, no when clauses matched the context.
[2022-06-01 12:47:09.911] [renderer1] [info] [KeybindingService]: + Ignoring single modifier ctrl due to it being pressed together with other keys.
```

If I change `when expression` of `selectNextSuggestion` to `none`. Still not working. This is log meassages:

```
[2022-06-01 12:52:50.564] [renderer1] [info] [KeybindingService]: / Received  keydown event - modifiers: [ctrl], code: ControlLeft, keyCode: 17, key: Control
[2022-06-01 12:52:50.565] [renderer1] [info] [KeybindingService]: | Converted keydown event - modifiers: [ctrl], code: ControlLeft, keyCode: 5 ('Ctrl')
[2022-06-01 12:52:50.566] [renderer1] [info] [KeybindingService]: \ Keyboard event cannot be dispatched in keydown phase.
[2022-06-01 12:52:50.584] [renderer1] [info] [KeybindingService]: / Received  keydown event - modifiers: [ctrl], code: KeyN, keyCode: 78, key: n
[2022-06-01 12:52:50.586] [renderer1] [info] [KeybindingService]: | Converted keydown event - modifiers: [ctrl], code: KeyN, keyCode: 44 ('N')
[2022-06-01 12:52:50.587] [renderer1] [info] [KeybindingService]: | Resolving ctrl+[KeyN]
[2022-06-01 12:52:50.588] [renderer1] [info] [KeybindingService]: \ From 1 keybinding entries, matched selectNextSuggestion, when: no when condition, source: user.
[2022-06-01 12:52:50.798] [renderer1] [info] [KeybindingService]: + Ignoring single modifier ctrl due to it being pressed together with other keys.
```

(Arrow keys work fine but they are too far away.)

My question is: **how can I make `selectNextSuggestion` shortcuts for `show all commands` work?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the correct action for the commands palette is not `selectNextSuggestion` but `workbench.action.quickOpenSelectNext`

Therefore, the following keyboard shortcut config should work as intended :

```json
  {
    "key": "ctrl+n",
    "command": "workbench.action.quickOpenSelectNext",
    "when": "inQuickOpen"
  },
  {
    "key": "ctrl+p",
    "command": "workbench.action.quickOpenSelectPrevious",
    "when": "inQuickOpen"
  }
```